# What are the best AJAX development tools?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, ide

can anyone please help me to identify the best AJAX development IDE or tools base on the advantages and disadvantages? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I like too much Aptana Studio.

Answer (score 1):

For the "tools" part of your question, I have found the following combo quite good:

[Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/firefox) + [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) + [FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/) + [FireRainbow](http://firerainbow.binaryage.com/) + [PageSpeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/download.html)  + [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the up-coming WebStorm from Jetbrains.

Upsides:
Support for Javascript and extended frameworks, such as YUI, JQuery, Dojo and Prototype; code completion, refactoring and code inspection. Mozilla-based Javascript debugger

From the help file:

> Smart, DOM-based, browser-type aware JavaScript code completion for:
>   Keywords, labels, variables, parameters and functions.
>   User defined and built-in JavaScript functions.
>   JavaScript namespaces.
>   JavaScript and AJAX error and syntax highlighting.
>   JavaScript and AJAX-aware refactorings:
>     Rename a file, function, variable, parameter, or label (both directly and via references).
>   Move/Copy a file.
>   Safe Delete a file.
>   Extract inlined script from HTML to a JS file.
>   Extract function.
>   Numerous JavaScript and AJAX-aware code inspections and quick-fixes.
>   JavaScript and AJAX Intention Actions that let create various application elements.
>   JavaScript and AJAX code formatting and folding.
>   JavaScript and AJAX code blocks, live

Downside:
Not free and not yet released (there's a 45 day trial on the Jetbrains website)

Comment: RubyMine and IDEA by JetBrains share the excellent JavaScript support that WebStorm has and are mature products. I use RubyMine for JavaScript/HTML/CSS development and it works very well.